# Kubuntu 11.04 music player doesn't have any sound

Tags: audio, mp3, kubuntu

I just installed Kubuntu 11.04 on my laptop and im playing mp3 files but hearing no sound at all.

I've downloaded the missing plugins but still got nothing, the song is being played while the system volume is at its highest, but no sound.

All of my programs are giving me the same result, like Banshee, movie player and Amarok audio player.

Comment: Please post the output of `pacmd info`.

Comment: im afraid its such a long Thing to be copied here i'd be glad if u tell me what should I look for .
thanks

Comment: @SpiXel:  You can use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) if you prefer.  If I only asked for a specific part, it probably would be fine and I'd have to ask you for a different part.  It's easier in the long run just to get the whole thing.  :-)

Comment: @Patches : I did so :) here's the link : http://pastebin.com/yPAfhf1K 
thanks again for the help

Comment: @SpiXel:  According to that, your video card supports HDMI audio in addition to the built-in sound card on your computer's motherboard.  Which do you use?  Also, try running `pacmd set-sink-mute 0 false && pacmd set-sink-mute 1 false` and see if that helps.  Both your integrated and HDMI outputs appear to be muted.

Comment: I used them both ( set-sink-mute 0 false and set-sink-mute 1 false ) but still no sounds :( 
i dont know what the problem shoud be :( and i dont know which one , either the Video card or built-in sound card , i use :(

Comment: @SpiXel:  Is your audio plugged in with a plug like that of a pair of headphones?  In that case you're using your internal audio.  If both your audio and video are going through the same cable to a newer TV or monitor, you're using HDMI.  Since it's far more likely you're using the former and it appears sound is trying go through the latter, I'm going to assume that's the case and post an answer on how to fix it.

Comment: hi , No , im using a laptop, its not plugged to anywhere , its the built in speaker of the laptop which is not playing any sounds

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the sound it muted under the software volume control, and that all the connections for the speaker are secure and plugged into the right ports.

Comment: I am using a laptop and the speaker works fine in Windows , and the Volume in software control is not muted too
There should be a problem with my Linux Configs but Im new in linux

Answer (score 0):

Open KDE"s System Settings application either in your K menu or by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `systemsettings` and pressing Enter.  Under *Hardware*, choose *Multimedia*:

[image: KDE System Settings with Multimedia highlighted]

Select *Phonon* (highlighted in red in the screenshot below) on the left side of the Multimedia settings window,  Now choose one of the items under *Audio Output* (yellow).  On the right, choose the one labeled something like *internal audio*.  Mine is labeled *Internal Audio Analog Stereo* (green) but yours might be slightly different.  Then, repeat that for every item under *Audio Output* (yellow).  Finally, click *Apply* (blue).

[[image: Phonon System Settings] <sup>click to zoom</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwIjZ.png)

Now, make sure you're volume is turned up and unmuted, and see if your audio works.

Comment: hi,Thanks for the help ,really,and well I'm using a laptop , its Sony Vaio F12 , and well the option U mentioned in Ur post , is faded in my OS ( its like the other 3 options below the one u highlighted ) and i cant chose it :( but there is two other options : Internal Audio Digital Stereo(IEC958) and one more that is :High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI) , i just can click and select these two , but the one u mentioned is faded and i cant chose it :(

Comment: @SpiXel:  Try the *Internal Audio Digital Stereo*.

Comment: it's not working either :( i've tried them both , there's sth up with my drivers or sth , and i dont know what is that

Comment: @SpiXel: Actually, a little Googling around for your particular laptop model indicates that you might be right about the drivers.  Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-alsa-lucid-generic` to update them to drivers backported from newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Patches : I did so but got the following error out of shell : Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-alsa-lucid-generic
maybe this package is not installed at all ?

Comment: @SpiXel:  Sorry about that!  You have to enable the *backports* repository in order to be able to install that package.  To do so, run `kdesudo software-properties-kde`, go to the *Updates* tab, and check *Unsupported updates*.  Then rerun that command.

Comment: @Patches : I did so too , and well I'm not familiar with the expressions , if returning means simply clicking close , i did so , and it again checked for new updates and I installed them all ,But im still having the same error ( package maybe not installed )

Comment: @Patches : i really appreciate your helps :) thank you so much :)

Comment: @SpiXel:  That's odd.  Let's try the newest drivers from the Ubuntu Audio team then.  Run this command on a terminal:  `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)`

Comment: seems everything's odd in my Kubuntu , i had to find my touchpad's driver first , then its multitouch and scroller's driver , and then its sound , at least i could find those two by googling , but this one seems so weird , no one has had this problem before , i did what u told me to do and I got two warnings for the latest command (sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver..... ) those are :  WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda6
cryptsetup and this one : WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab , sorry again for being nerd in linux :(

Comment: @SpiXel:  Those were just warnings, so the command theoretically completed successfully.  They have something to do with filesystem encryption, which I know next to nothing about.  If you have further trouble related to that, please ask a new question.  In the meantime, try rebooting and see if your sound works.

Comment: @Patches : this is what i got : linux-alsa-driver-modules-2.6.38-8-generic is already the newest version. but still no sound :( and it was after reboot , i tired the whole thing for once again , to see if there was any changes , and i saw that it was , but still no sounds

Comment: I searched for alsa in synaptic package manager , and I found that none of alsa driver modules are installed on my system , i checked them , but they appeared to be broken packages , the boxes was red , and I got an error trying to install them , isnt it because of that ?

Comment: @SpiXel:  I'm very sorry, I misread your original question as being version 10.04 instead of 11.04, so not only will those packages not work, what I thought was your problem shouldn't be a problem in that version at all.  I'll look into problems there might be with 11.04 that would affect you.

Comment: @SpiXel:  Open a terminal, run `alsamixer`, and make sure all your levels are turned up.

Comment: ye , they were all turned up ! i'll go for a reboot , will tell the results

Comment: nO, still no sounds , while all the levels are turned up :-<